# How to add specific event counters to Perf whilst keeping the default output/events?

Tags: linux, performance, optimization, x86, perf

I'm profiling using Perf, currently generating this output:

```
perf stat -C 3 -B  ./my_app

Performance counter stats for 'CPU(s) 3':

     23,191.79 msec cpu-clock                 #    1.000 CPUs utilized          
           800      context-switches          #   34.495 /sec                   
             2      cpu-migrations            #    0.086 /sec                   
         1,098      page-faults               #   47.344 /sec                   
    55,871,690      cycles                    #    0.002 GHz                    
    30,950,148      stalled-cycles-frontend   #   55.40% frontend cycles idle   
    64,157,302      instructions              #    1.15  insn per cycle         
                                              #    0.48  stalled cycles per insn
    12,845,079      branches                  #  553.863 K/sec                  
       227,892      branch-misses             #    1.77% of all branches
```

I'd like to add some specific event counters not listed above.

However, when I list them explicitly, I lose the metadata in the right hand column and the default counters all disappear:

```
 perf stat -e cache-misses -B ./my_app

 Performance counter stats for 'CPU(s) 3':

           207,463      cache-misses                                               

       4.437709174 seconds time elapsed
```

As you can see, the right-most column has disappeared. I'd like to keep this column, but add specific events.

1. Is it possible to take the default set of events using `-B` and add additional events?
2. If not, if I manually create my list of events, how do I keep the right-most column with the /sec etc?

Comment: The `/sec` is computed if `task-clock` is one of the events.  I don't know of a convenient / short-command-line way to add one extra event, but the simple way is just to include all those events in your list, like `perf stat --all-user -etask-clock,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,instructions,uops_issued.any,uops_executed.thread,machine_clears.memory_ordering` as in the examples in [Why does this code execute more slowly after strength-reducing multiplications to loop-carried additions?](//stackoverflow.com/a/72333152) and [mov-elimination](//stackoverflow.com/a/44193770)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a convenient / short-command-line way to add one extra event.  The man page doesn't seem to mention one.

**I usually include the default events manually in the `--event=` list**.

```
perf stat --all-user -etask-clock,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,instructions,uops_issued.any,uops_executed.thread
```

You can use `-e` or `--event=` more than once, e.g. `-etask-clock,instructions,...`  `-e uops_issued.any,uops_executed.thread` if that makes editing the command-line easier to easily remove custom events with a control-w instead of having to alt+backspace to kill a word at a time in bash line editing.

See examples in some of my answers, such as the following where I included a `perf stat` command and actual output.

- *[Why does this code execute more slowly after strength-reducing multiplications to loop-carried additions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72306573/why-does-this-code-execute-more-slowly-after-strength-reducing-multiplications-t/72333152#72333152)*
- *[Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all/44193770#44193770)*

**You can add the events for a "metric group" to the default events** with
`-M L3_Cache_Access_BW` for example, as shown in *[How to calculate the L3 cache bandwidth by using the performance counters linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72597540/how-to-calculate-the-l3-cache-bandwidth-by-using-the-performance-counters-linux/72597682#72597682)*. But not arbitrary single events.

**The `-d` or `-dd` options** can add events to whatever you specified with `-e`, (e.g. `perf stat -e uops_executed.thread,task-clock -dd  awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0;i<10000000;i++){}}'`) but there's no option to add the default events.

On Intel hardware, each core has fixed counters for `cycles` (`clk_unhalted_...`) and `instructions` (`inst_retired.any`), so always counting those doesn't take away from the number of events you can count with the programmable counters without multiplexing, e.g. 4 on a Skylake with hyperthreading.  (`perf` may not know about that, treating `cycles` and `instructions` just like other events.  So if it does have to multiplex it may sometimes be counting fewer events than it could be, and thus having a worse duty cycle for some events than it could.)  The `context-switches` and other default events are *software* events, counted by the kernel not by the PMU, so any number of them can be enabled at once, and don't interact with multiplexing.

---

**Secondary info annotations are just ratios of two events**, printed if both are counted.

- The `/sec` secondary info is computed if `task-clock` or `duration-time` is one of the events.    (Related: *[Run time and reported cycle counts in linux perf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71380089/run-time-and-reported-cycle-counts-in-linux-perf)* re: system-wide counting and/or `--all-user` or `instructions:u` leading to low CPU GHz (cycles/second) if not many unhalted clock cycles happened (in user-space) across the CPUs you were counting.)
- For `instructions`, the default secondary info is IPC, so it's computed if you also measure `cycles`.
- For `cache-misses`, the secondary info is percent of `cache-references`.  (And no, you don't know which level of cache perf will choose to count with `cache-misses`, or what event `cache-references` maps to. These names are super generic.)  Similar for other events that count cache misses in specific levels.

---

The `-B` option is on by default, and totally orthogonal to all of the event-selection and secondary annotation stuff.  It's what uses thousands separators when printing large numbers.  Use `--no-big-num` for the opposite, to get numbers you can copy/paste into a calculator.